# Windows Azure Cache 2.2 SDK No such host is known error

Tags: caching, azure

Caching was working fine until I upgraded Windows Azure Cache to 2.2.0.0.

```
DataCache cache = new DataCache("none");
```

When the code hits that line I get the error:

```
No such host is known

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known

[SocketException (0x2af9): No such host is known]
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AsyncResultNoResult.EndInvoke() +172
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AsyncResult`1.EndInvoke() +40
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketConnectionFactory.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +75
   Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.TcpClientChannelFactory.TcpConnectionCallback(IAsyncResult result) +182

[DataCacheException: ErrorCode<ERRCA0017>:SubStatus<ES0006>:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. For on-premises cache clusters, also verify the following conditions. Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client account, and check that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed through the firewall on all cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the server must be greater than or equal to the serialized object size sent from the client.). Additional Information : The client was trying to communicate with the server: net.tcp://ProjectName:24233.]
```

I see people in the past have had this. I am running the 2.2 SDK and all dll references are to the 2.2 versions, nothing is referencing 2.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check entry in web.config file and make sure all is well there?

Comment: I can't see any differences. Are there any diagnostics I can do to narrow down the problem?

Comment: You may find this link helpful in configuring cache diagnostics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914135.aspx#DiagnosticLevel. When we ran into issues with cache, we set the diagnostic level to 4.

Comment: I just upgraded to MVC 5.1.0 and Razor 3.1.0 etc. and caching works again now...

Comment: I'm running into this issue and using MVC 5.1.0 and Razor 3.1.0.  Did you do anything else to get it working again?  Everything works fine locally but I cannot deploy it to Azure.

Comment: That's all I updated to fix it. 3.1.1 and 5.1.1 came out today. As it wasn't working locally for me I never tried deploying it. The new versions work for me too, see if they fix the issue.